# Include an If statement in a SQL Server trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm currently struggling in a database management class. I have been tasked with creating a trigger that prints a message if a customer makes a reservation for the first time. My code so far is as follows

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ResNewTrigger] 
ON [dbo].[Reservation] 
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @cid CHAR(4)   
    DECLARE @res_counts INT    
    SELECT @cid = CustomerNum FROM inserted    

    SELECT @res_counts = COUNT(*) 
    FROM dbo.Reservation 
    WHERE CustomerNum = @cid 

    IF @res_counts = 0 THEN
        PRINT  'A reservation is made for the first time from customer' + @cid;
    END IF;
END;
```

This throws the errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ResNewTrigger, Line 20 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ResNewTrigger, Line 22 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   Incorrect syntax near ';'.

I must not know the proper syntax or something but I have had zero luck finding how to solve this issue.

Comment: One issue is that you are assuming there will only be 1 row in `inserted` - you can never do that as `inserted` will contain as many rows as are updated/inserted, and you have to be able to handle that. There are many SQL Server trigger tutorials around which show how.

Comment: If you check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `if/begin/end` doesn't start with `then` nor finish with `end if`.

Comment: You need to get into the habit of checking docs.Otherwise you'll need to get used to people telling you to rtfm. Everything is just a google away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error in your `IF` statement is the least of your problems with regards to the trigger (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to correct the `IF` statement).

Your trigger is wrong because you are assuming that `inserted` has one row.  Such an assumption is NEVER safe.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ResNewTrigger] 
   ON  [dbo].[Reservation] 
   AFTER INSERT
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @cids VARCHAR(MAX);

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    SELECT @cids = STRING_AGG(i.cid, ', ')
    FROM inserted i JOIN
         Reservation r
         ON r.customerNum = i.customerNum
    GROUP BY i.cid
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;   -- this row is already in reservation
    IF @cids <> ''
    BEGIN
        PRINT  'A reservation is made for the first time from customer(s) ' + @cids;
    END;
END;
```

This concatenates the cids together using `string_agg()`.  In earlier versions of SQL Server, you need a UDF or some other mechanism to aggregate the strings.

I removed the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` portions of the trigger s well.  You certainly cannot get a new reservation for a customer on a `DELETE`.  On an `UPDATE`, it is more questionable.  However, it is difficult (but not impossible) to differentiate between a change to a single record and inserting a single record.

Comment: I'm quite surprised at how this could get a downvote.  Is someone (anonymously) suggesting NOT taking into account that `inserted` could have multiple rows?

Comment: @DaleK . . . If you only address the syntax error you are leaving a trigger with a MAJOR BUG in it.  That would seem to be the bigger issue.  The OP does not know how to write a correct trigger.